# Django URLs without function in views

Tags: python, django, url, django-urls

I tried to make a multi-upload system.  I have a functionnal page music.html, which list all musics and have some buttons to access to another page to add music.

'Add Music' should be the button's name instead of 'Music'.

music.html :

```
<legend class="scheduler-border"><a href="{% url 'webgui.views.addmusic' %}" style="margin-bottom: 3px" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a> Add Music </legend>
```

However, I don't need to execute any functions from music.html to addmusic.html...

My urls.py :

```
url(r'^music/$','webgui.views.music'),
url(r'^addmusic/$','webgui.views.addmusic'),
url(r'^addmusic/add/$', 'webgui.views.multiple_uploader'),
```

Is there a way to redirect music.html to addmusic.html without executing 'webgui.views.addmusic'  ?? 
Really, I just need to display the form.

EDIT :

Yes, finally it works with my addmusic function in views.py :

```
def addmusic(request):
return render(request, 'addmusic.html')
```

So it means an URL necessarily have a corresponding function  ??  I can't pass "href=addmusic.html" in my template ?  Just to know ...

Comment: when clicking on 'Add Music', your 'addmusic' view will be called and if it displays a 'form' it will simply display the 'form'. what does your 'addmusic' view do? Does it displays a 'form'?
Share your 'addmusic' view code , it will be helpful to figure out the actual problem.

Comment: use generic 'TemplateView' and pass the 'html' page as argument.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `TemplateView`.

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

    url(r'^addmusic/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="addmusic.html"), name='add-muusic'),
```